# Como obtener solo ' en una cadena '''

Tags: c#

Lo que dice el titulo, habia probado hacer solo trim de la cadena usando ''' pero me elimina toda el string, lo que pensaba era hacer un substring del para solo obtener el de en medio, pero como es que prodria hacer con una cadena ''''''''' que son 3 ' seguidos, agradezco cualquier ayuda

```
string KeytoTrim="";
var auxif = transicion.Simbolo.Count(f => f == '\'');
if (auxif>2)
{

}
else
{
  KeytoTrim= transicion.Simbolo.Trim('\'');
}
```

Lo que hace este codigo es que recibe un Simbolo que puede ser algo como 'U' 'O' '>' y puede venir ''' pero cuando usaba solo trim lo que pasaba era que borraba todo el string. Lo que pense hacer era que si venia mas de 2 ' (de inicio y de fin) era hacer "algo" pero eso es lo que no encuentro como hacer

Comment: Es complicado de entender. Podes poner el codigo que haces? y que queres obtener?

Comment: Listo ya agregue el codigo y una corta explicacion

Comment: Sigo sin entender. Queres obtener un caracter o cuantos caracteres iguales tiene un string? y luego hacer que?

Comment: Lo que quiero obtener es el character que va en medio de 2  ' ' y no se como hacerlo si vienen 3 o mas cadenas asi (''') 3 comillas o mas o sea obtener la comilla en medio de otras 2 '''

Comment: Ok, creo que necesitas usar Expresiones Regulares.

Comment: Te dejo el link. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo, segun entendi lo que quieres hacer suponiendo que el caracter que queres obtener esta dentro de una ' (comilla simple) o mas de una '' (comilla simple).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string texto = "holaaa'''a''''";
        string exp = "(\'[a]\')"; // Esta es tu expresion, te encuentra cualquier caracter dentro de ' ' porque eso te marca como inicio y fin. Le pido que me busque la letra "a" y que este encerrado 'Comilla simple".

        ExpresionRegular.EncontrarExpresion(texto, exp);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

     public static void EncontrarExpresion(string texto, string exp)
    {
        MatchCollection encontrado = Regex.Matches(texto, exp);

        foreach (var item in encontrado)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```